# NSURLConnection not downloading all data

Tags: nsurlconnection, nsdata, nsurlrequest, yahoo-finance

How comes when i run this code, the data that gets downloaded seems to have cropped off some information from the first row?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?   s=GOOG&d=6&e=27&f=2012&g=d&a=6&b=25&c=2011&ignore=.csv"];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

The data then gets sorted here:

```
NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
strData = [strData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close" withString:@""];
NSArray* arrUncleanDataLine = [strData componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
NSMutableArray *arrCleanDataLine = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc]init];
```

The top line gets cropped off. Why is this? Is it because NSData can only hold a certain amount of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you yourself remove the first line "Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close" by this code:

```
strData = [strData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close" withString:@""];
```

So just comment this line.

Comment: I meant the second line. Here is the output:

Comment: As you can see the second item of data starts with a date, and the first does not.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it. When i was downloading the data it was not appending the old data and adding it to the new data.